# gulpのwatchでbrowserifyの自動トランスパイルを実行するとCannot find module '~/testproj/src/app.js' from '~/testproj'エラーが発生する

Tags: node.js, gulp, browserify

タイトル通りなのですが、gulpを利用してbrowserifyのトランスパイルをファイル監視による自動実行させようとしています。

gulpfile.jsは以下のように設定しました。

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

gulp.task('browserify', function(){
  browserify({entries: ['src/app.js']})
  .bundle()
  .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./js'))
});

gulp.task('default', function() {
  gulp.watch('src/app.js', ['browserify']);
});
```

コマンドラインで`gulp browserify`を実行したところ、無事コードがトランスパイルされたのですが、watchを利用したファイル監視による自動実行をさせると、対象のファイルの更新した瞬間以下のエラーが発生します。

```
Cannot find module '~/testproj/src/app.js' from '~/testproj'
```

Cannot find moduleということで、app.jsが見つからないということなのですが、実際`~/testproj/src`ディレクトリの中にapp.jsは存在しますので、何がいけないのかさっぱりわかりません。

何かお気付きの点がございましたらご指摘お願いいたします。

Answer (score -1):

直接的な原因は分かりませんが、browserifyのwatchはwatchifyを使うのが一般的です。

https://github.com/substack/watchify